# How to achieve android placeholder effect like google news app

Tags: android, google-news

I found that in **The Google** news app, the placeholder effect is very good, and I want to apply that effect to my app.

As known, when coding, we usually use default text, default background, or totally a bland activity before data has been loaded. But in google news, I found that each `textView`  `cardView`, or other layout, show a gray-rounded view before data loaded. That's cool.

Here's a screenshot:
[image]
[image]
Before the news loaded, the `Activity` shows nothing but with gray-rounded placeholder views in the same position where will be filled with data.

How can I achieve such effect simply, or the only way is write many redundant codes and `setVisibility(View.GONE, View.Visiable)`

Comment: You can use Facebook's [Shimmer library](https://github.com/facebook/shimmer-android) for that effect.

Comment: This is only an Asynchronous loading: the ListView/Scroll View is initialized using placeholders and in the same time a different Thread is loading the data. When the Thread has finished to load them it updates the same ListView/Scroll View using them

Comment: Idk why this has been closed, that's a good question and that was exactly what I was looking for... it could have different answers for this

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**`Facebook’s Shimmer Library`**](https://code.fb.com/android/shimmer-for-android/)

How to use

Add Shimmer dependency to your `build.gradle` and rebuild the project.

```
dependencies {           

    // Shimmer
    implementation 'com.facebook.shimmer:shimmer:0.1.0@aar'
}
```

add in your layout.xml file

```
<com.facebook.shimmer.ShimmerFrameLayout
     android:id=“@+id/shimmer_view_container”
     android:layout_width=“wrap_content”
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     shimmer:duration="5000" // Number of milliseconds to animate one ‘sweep’                                           
>
      // your complex view here

</com.facebook.shimmer.ShimmerFrameLayout>
```

Now in your activity

```
ShimmerFrameLayout container = 
    (ShimmerFrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.shimmer_view_container);
  container.startShimmerAnimation();
```

Here is the good article for it [**`Android Content Placeholder Animation like Facebook using Shimmer`**](https://www.androidhive.info/2018/01/android-content-placeholder-animation-like-facebook-using-shimmer/)

Comment: According to the article you mentioned, The library seems only add an animation to the whole layout but not the gray-round placeholder. It seems I still need to create a placeholder layout which is similar to the actual item layout that will be filled with data. Actually I doesn't need such animation, I only want to show the placeholder before the net request ended.